# Getting array from textboxes and select boxes in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a way to capture information via jQuery from fields that have the same name. Below is an example of code for the form...

```js
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
        var field1 =  $("input[name='field1[]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Text input-->
 <form >
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1[]">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1[]">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1[]">
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1[]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>


<!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->

</form>
```

My question is how do I include the selection box as well to variable `field1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `select[name='field1[]']` to your selector and separate it with coma, like this:

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    var field1 =  $("input[name='field1[]'], select[name='field1[]']")
        .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

});
```

More about multiple selectors: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Thx . This is what I needed.